# How to get all the linked elements (rows) which are repeated in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get all the food-id which has been consumed by a customer. If i give an input of lets say a customerId = C15, then it should return all the food_id's which customer has a link.
I tried something.

```py
import datetime
import random
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

df = pd.DataFrame({
'food_id':['B1', 'CF', 'C1', 'CF', 'B1', 'IO', 'B1', 'FT', 'BR','CF', 'C1', 'SM', 'IC','B1', 'SM'],
'purch_amt':[150.5, 270.65, 65.26, 110.5, 948.5, 2400.6, 5760, 1983.43, 2480.4, 250.45, 75.29, 3045.6, 500, 500, 250],
'ord_date': ['05-10-2022','09-10-2022','05-10-2022','08-17-2022','10-09-2022','07-27-2022','10-09-2022','10-10-2022','10-10-2022','06-17-2022','07-08-2022','04-25-2022','02-08-2022','08-08-2022','07-09-2022'],
'customer_id':['C31','C31','D35','D31','C35','D31','C35','D31','D35','C31','D35','D35','D35','C35','C38']})


def get_mostly_ordered_food_id():
    print('Max food_id ordered')
    result = df['food_id'].value_counts().rename_axis('food_id').reset_index(name='counts')
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(result)
    print(df2.head(3))

def show_data():
    result = df.groupby(['customer_id'])
    print(result.first())

def test_add_data():
    foodID = ['B1', 'CF', 'C1', 'IO', 'FT', 'BR', 'IC', 'SM']
    customerID = ['C31','D35','D31','C35','C38']
    date = 'Test-Data'
    for i in range(0,10):
        df.loc[len(df.index)] = [random.choice(customerID), random.choice(foodID), date, 500]
    print(df)
    get_mostly_ordered_food_id()
```

If I give an input, say a customer ID, then it should return all the food-id which has been consumed. Also I should not repeat.

Trying to get e.g. input "C15" (which is customer id)

It should return e.g. "B1, C2" (which are food ids) with no duplication. (If any duplication is there, it should throw a warning.)

(*NB: More context on this assignment can be read in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74711326/how-can-i-write-python-code-to-manipulate-a-restaurant-log).*)

Comment: Can't see you have: customerId = C15 in the customer_id column. Also not in food_id = C2.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foods_of_customer(df, customer_id):
   foods = df['food_id'].loc[df['customer_id'] == customer_id]
   return foods.values
```

The method `df.loc[]` returns all the row satisfying the condition in it.
The method `food.values` converts the dataframe into a NunPy array. You can after that apply `np.unique` to avoid repeatations.